# libgit2: How to mark resolution

Tags: libgit2

I can't figure out how to mark a resolution after resolving merge conflicts with libgit2. calling git status on the repo returns Unmerged paths: and says both added: <'myfilename'>

Edit: Her is example code of how I got it to work for future reference.

```cpp
    git_merge_options merge_opts = GIT_MERGE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_merge(repo, annotated_commit, 1, &merge_opts, &checkout_opts);
    
    git_index* index = nullptr;
    git_repository_index(&index, repo);    
    if (git_index_has_conflicts(index))
    {
      git_index_conflict_iterator* conflicts = nullptr;
      git_index_entry entries[3];
      git_index_conflict_iterator_new(&conflicts, index);
      while (git_index_conflict_next(&entries[0], &entries[1], &entries[2], conflicts)
        != GIT_ITEROVER) 
      {
         //Write desired content to file in working copy         
         handle_conflict(entries[2]->path); 
         git_index_conflict_remove(index, entries[2]->path);
         git_index_add_bypath(index, entries[2]->path);
      }
      git_index_conflict_iterator_free(conflicts);
      git_index_conflict_cleanup(index);
      
      //At this point index does not have more conflicts so write it
      git_index_write(index);
    }

    git_commit* parents[2];
    git_reference* head_ref = nullptr;
    git_repository_head(&head_ref, repo);
    git_reference_peel((git_object**)&parents[0], head_ref, GIT_OBJECT_COMMIT);
    git_commit_lookup(&parents[1], repo, git_annotated_commit_id(annotated));

    git_tree* tree = nullptr;
    git_oid tree_oid, commit_oid; 
    git_index_write_tree(&tree_oid, index);
    git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_oid);
    git_commit_create(&commit_oid, repo, 
      git_reference_name(head_ref), signature, signature, NULL, "Merge", 
      tree, 2, (const git_commit**)parents);
    git_tree_free(tree);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing your "try to commit" step, so it's not clear to me yet - are you converting the index to a tree and trying to commit and that's what failing?  Or are you calling `git_index_write` and then trying to commit the on-disk index?

Comment: @Edward Thomson Thank you for feedback. I'm writing the index to a tree and then committing the tree. I'll update the code with a codepath simmilar to what I'm using.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I just realized that in order to get the resolved resolution into the tree I need to write it first. I updated the code so it works now. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Glad it's working for you!